# How do I force install updates that `softwareupdate -l` doesn't show (but should)?

Tags: command-line, software-update

(16in 2019 Intel MBP, 12.3.1)

So I'm trying to apply software updates that should get me from 12.3.1 to 12.5, and am well past the stage of trying to get the system Software Update tool to apply them. I know they're there, and OSX knows they're there, because `/var/log/install.log` shows

```
2022-08-05 11:30:08-07 <machine> com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.remoteservice[1097]: Controller: Received availableUpdatesChanged notification; new updates: []; new major updates: [012-42714, 012-06873, 002-79225, 012-40387, 012-22320, 012-08272, 002-77154, 002-65695, 002-57023, 002-42341, 002-23589, 071-78704, 001-68446, 001-51042, 001-36801]
2022-08-05 11:30:08-07 <machine> softwareupdated[325]: MSU updates found: (
        )
2022-08-05 11:30:08-07 <machine> com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.remoteservice[1097]: SUOSUShimController: Armed: 0, with mode: 0, date: (null), updates queued for later: (
        )
2022-08-05 11:30:08-07 <machine> softwareupdated[325]: Adding client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=930, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
2022-08-05 11:30:08-07 <machine> SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[930]: AssertionMgr: Cancel com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-BadgingCountChanged assertion for pid 930, id 0x84F3
2022-08-05 11:30:08-07 <machine> SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[930]: SUOSUAuthenticationManager: Disabling local authentication requirement
2022-08-05 11:30:08-07 <machine> softwareupdated[325]: Adding client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=930, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
2022-08-05 11:30:08-07 <machine> SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[930]: AssertionMgr: Could not cancel com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-BadgingCountChanged assertion - no assertion found for pid 930
```

So it knows there are several major updates, but they don't show as "MSU updates", and trying to naively install one of the listed updates by ID gets nowhere:

```
<machine>:~ root# softwareupdate -i 012-42714
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
2022-08-05 11:39:09.381 softwareupdate[2141:39211] XType: com.apple.fonts is not accessible.
2022-08-05 11:39:09.382 softwareupdate[2141:39211] XType: XTFontStaticRegistry is enabled.
012-42714: No such update
No updates are available.
```

Where do I go from here trying to get these updates installed?
The machine is controlled by an MDM (Jamf, specifically).

Comment: Is this machine controlled by an MDM?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that, yes, jamf specifically. (although if jamf were behaving as expected, presumably I would not be having the problems motivating this post)

Comment: More likely, the actual administrators of the machine are blocking these updates.